# aws s3 - browser upload using post - gwt & java

Tags: amazon-web-services, gwt, amazon-s3, upload

I am working on a wgt webapp and would like to upload files to s3 from the browser.
Since my credentials are on the server, I need to create the signature on the server and send it to the client to be able to ulpoad.

here is the code I am using:
-dateStamp is in the right format  - yyyyMMdd
-policy is base64 encoded - I double checked that

```
public static String getSignatureForS3Upload(final String dateStamp, final String policy) {
    byte[] signingKey = null;
    byte[] signature = null;
    String strSignature = null;
    try {
        signingKey = AwsUtill.getSignatureKey(AppConfig.getS3SecretKey(), dateStamp,
                AppConfigShared.getMyAwsS3RegionName(), "s3");
        signature = HmacSHA256(policy, signingKey);
        strSignature = bytesToHex(signature);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       // log
    }
    ServerDBLogger.log(Level.INFO, byteArrayToHex(signature));
    ServerDBLogger.log(Level.INFO, bytesToHex(signature));
    return strSignature;

private static byte[] HmacSHA256(final String data, final byte[] key) throws Exception {
    String algorithm = "HmacSHA256";
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
    mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm));
    return mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}

private static byte[] getSignatureKey(final String key, final String dateStamp, final String regionName,
        final String serviceName) throws Exception {
    byte[] kSecret = ("AWS4" + key).getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] kDate = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
    byte[] kRegion = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
    byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
    byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);
    return kSigning;
}

final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
public static String bytesToHex(final byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

With the genarated signature I get an error message: 
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

What am I doing wrong?
Is there any good tutorial or sample code to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There have been changes to the AWS signature process - the version at this time (May 2016) is AWS Signature version 4 (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html). You need to be careful when looking at examples and Stackoverflow etc that the information relates to the same signature version you are using as they don't mix well.

I started using the AWS SDK for an angular/node file upload but eventually found it easier to generate the policy on the server (node.js) side without the SDK. There is a good example (albeit node based which may not be what you are looking for) here: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/wiki/Direct-S3-upload-and-Node-signing-example (but note the issue with the S3 bucket name here: AngularJs Image upload to S3 ).

One key thing to watch is that you correctly include the file content type in the policy generation and that this content type properly matches the content type of the file you are actually uploading.